# Import TypeScript namespace in JSDoc

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

the current structure of files in a Node.js **Javascript** project looks like this:

```
// types.d.ts
export type K = { id: string }
// ...
export as namespace Types
```

```
// test.js
/**
 * @namespace {import('./path/to/type/definition/types').Types} Types
 * @param {Types.K} props
 */
const testFunction = (props) => console.log(props.id)
```

The idea is to define types that assist code suggestion / auto-completion, however, the editor (VS code) does not recognize this way. I've tried various ways of writing the import function (`import('...').Types`, `import Types from '...'`, with or without `.d.ts`, etc.), but none of them worked. I do not want to import all types one by one, therefore, any answer that imports the namespace or imports types all at once is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The [`export as namespace Types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#umd-modules) already defines `Types` **globally**. There is no need to declare `Types` from a `@namespace` on usage, just use it like the following:

```js
/**
 * @param {Types.K} props
 */
const testFunction = (props) => console.log(props.id)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: May I ask if you have `.d.ts` file open in the editor when checking its type in `.js`? With `.d.ts` open the type can be found and linked by vscode, but after I close the `.d.ts` it no longer resolves

Comment: No. It just works as is even without the `.d.ts` open. Just make sure `tsconfig.json` includes both the `*.ts` and `*.js` files or none at all.

Comment: Ok, then unfortunately maybe this is not the answer I am looking for... I don't want to configure a `tsconfig.json` file for a pure JavaScript project... nevertheless thank you for your help :D

Comment: You can configure a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) instead and it should work.